# authenticate using sql server logins

Tags: c#, authentication, passwords, connection-string

is a good practice to authenticate using sql server logins? 
for example, in an application, ask for username and password, and then try to connect to the database using those credentials? (maybe to retrieve user information), and then subsequents connections in the same way. 
This way i have no need to store neither the user or password in the connectionstring, only the server and database information. 
i know i must create a database user and login for each user, what is the downside of doing that way?

i apologize for my English is not native, also is my first post :)

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, there is no problem until you give appropriate permissions to the user in the database server. For ex: application uses Northwind database but user is not given access or appropriate permissions to access the Northwind database, user will see exception. For this to work, we need to set impersonation to true.

To enhance it further create a AD group and give this group appropriate permissions on databases. Now, add users to this group to minimize errors while setting up each new user.

Comment: thank you for the answer. would you think is better the connectionstring for the entire application connections, with user and password on it(encrypted), and manage the user passwords in a sepparate table, only for the login - approach?

Comment: For intranet applications, it is better not to mention the userid and password in web.config file. It is usually a standard to allow access to the SQL servers via windows authentication. For internet applications, you can prefer forms authentication and hash + encryptedpassword in the users table.

Comment: ok. for web applications then use windows authentication for connections. but would you think is better for a winforms application? 1.connectionstring with password encrypted for all connection and separate users table only for authentication, or 2.connectionstring without password and all connections using credentials asked in the authentication process? i want to know wich one is better aproach.

Comment: Second approach is used as a standard.

Comment: thank you. im asking this because i have seen many applications(winforms and webforms) that uses aproach 1 even without encrypting the config file, while no one using approach 2. Please, do you know some tutorial or article explaining the approach 2? thank you.